# Python - JSON ValueError: Extra data

Tags: python, json

I am trying to join `json` files:

```
path_to_json = 'generated_playlists/p1/'
json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]
```

`json` files are structured like this:

```
{"user1": {"Wild Wood": 1.0, "You Do Something To Me": 1.0, "Reprise": 1.0}}
```

but when I do:

```
for js in json_files:
    with open(os.path.join(path_to_json, js)) as json_file:
        pd_data = json.load(json_file)
```

I get:

`ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 145 - line 1 column 721 (char 144 - 720)`

what is wrong with `json.load()`?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the specific JSON file, not `json.load`

Comment: check if the files have the apropiarte format. You can also use `try` and `except` so only bad files don't get loaded.

Comment: @edgarcosta how would I do that in the code above? I would accept that as an answer

Comment: Sorry, @HEADLESS_ONE already answered. I hope it helps, otherwise if you still have problems write again I can try to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @edgarcosta, you can handle the `ValueError` in a `try-except` block in your `for` loop, like so:

```
import os
import json
import sys

path_to_json = 'generated_playlists/p1/'
json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]

for js in json_files:
    json_path = os.path.join(path_to_json, js)
    with open(json_path) as json_file:
        try:
            pd_data = json.load(json_file)
        except ValueError:
            sys.stderr.write('Could not parse JSON file: {0}'.format(json_path))
```

This should help you identify which JSON files are unable to be read.

Comment: @data_garden, I did a small assign `os.path.join(path_to_json, js)` to `json_path`. This way, the ValueError should print in std err with the file path (not its content, as I had mistakenly done before). 

Hope this helps!